Finite operators to express infinite numbers of operators with special conditions
Suppose  that we have an infinite number of $\mathbb{C}-$linear operators $\{A_0,A_1,\cdots\}$ where $A_i:V\to W$ and $i\in \mathbb{N}$.
If $\dim V$ and $\dim W$ are both finite dimensional and we have a $\mathbb{C}$-linear operators $\varphi:\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)$ such that $\varphi^m(A_0)=A_m$ for any $m\ge 0$.
I want to  prove there exists a finite number of operators $f_{k,\lambda}:V\to W$ $(k\ge 0, \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^*)$ such that  for any $v\in V$
$$A_m(v)=\sum_{k\ge 0,  \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^*}\lambda^m m^k f_{\lambda,k}(v).
$$
Here are my attempts:

Since $\dim V$ and $\dim W$ are finite, we have
$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)$ is also finite dimensional.
Then by the Jordan decomposition, $\varphi=\varphi_1+\varphi_2$ where
$\varphi_1\circ\varphi_2=\varphi_2\circ \varphi_1$, $\varphi_1$ is diagonalizable
and $\varphi_2^S=0$ for some $S\ge 1$. So for any $m\ge 0$
$$A_m=\varphi^m(A_0)=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 m\\
 j\\
\end{array} \right)\varphi_2^j~\varphi_1^{m-s}(A_0).$$
We assume that $A_0=a_1f_1+\cdots +a_nf_n$ where $f_1,\cdots.f_n$ is the basis of  $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)$ and $\varphi_1(f_i)=\lambda_if_i$.
Thus $$A_m=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{m}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 m\\
 j\\
\end{array} \right)\lambda^{m-s} \varphi_2^j~(a_if_i)$$

My question is how can I get the desired result from above attempts?
Or I hope there's a new way to solve it, too.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
